# htaccess redirect index.php to root (including subdomains)

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to redirect index.php files to the root /, I've searched around and found several snippets of code similar to:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index.php 
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This however won't work for subdomains, example below:

1. I have a subdomain: subdomain.domain.com
2. A user visits http://subdomain.domain.com/index.php
3. Using the htaccess above they are redirected to http://www.domain.com/ rather than http://subdomain.domain.com/

Does anyone know how to adjust the htaccess above so it will take into account the subdomain and redirect them to the appropriate location?

e.g. if a user visits http://subdomain.domain.com/index.php they will go to http://subdomain.domain.com/

Bonus Points:

Is there a htaccess that can just apply this rule to all folders?

So for any folder with an index.php they will just be redirected to it's root e.g. http://subdomain.domain.com/folder1/folder2/index.php would automatically go to http://subdomain.domain.com/folder1/folder2/

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Do this:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index\.php 
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: This worked great, thanks! For anyone with the same problem, if you have a subdomain, you might be forced to select a folder for it to sit in, make sure you create/select a folder out of public_html or this htaccess will try and redirect to that folder. e.g. i have subdomain.domain.com which had it's files stored in www.domain.com/subdomain, this htaccess would send users to subdomain.domain.com/subdomain whenever they visited subdomain.domain.com/index.php but if you place the folder outside of public_html you don't get this problem.

Comment: @ThinkingMonkey Could you fix the dot in the regex `index.php`? I believe you intended to write `index\.php` :)

Comment: @ThinkingMonkey I realise this is 5 years old, however I was wondering if it was possible to redirect "/index" as well as "/index.php"? I have code that removes any .php extensions to make the url's cleaner, however the I'd like domain.com/index to redirect to domain.com if possible?

Comment: @ThinkingMonkey Don't you need a `\.` in the second `index.php`, too?

Comment: @ThinkingMonkey And isn't the `RewriteCond` redundant in this case?

Comment: `RewriteRule ^index\.php/(.+)$ /$1 [R,L]` This worked for me

Comment: @ChuckLeButt The `RewriteCond` directive that checks against `THE_REQUEST` is required if you are internally rewriting the request to `index.php` later (a front-controller pattern). Otherwise, it probably is "redundant".

Comment: @HomayoonAhmadi Although that's solving a different problem. And in the context of this question, would not remove `index.php` so would not be a solution to this problem.

Answer (score 18):

I based the following code on [@ThinkingMonkey's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9372938/1608072)

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.(php|html?)$ /$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

It redirects URIs ending with *index.php*, *index.htm* or *index.html* to */*. Works with subdirectories, too.

Also, notice the `NC` flag. It makes it case-insensitive. So it works even if the URI is in upper-case such as *INDEX.PHP*.

Answer (score -4):

Can be use this

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php/(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: That certainly appears to be the exact opposite of what was requested.

Comment: This is the best solution. Other works only if you have domain.ext/index.php but does not works for doamin.ext/index.php/some_argument/ -> domain.ext/some_argument/  .

Comment: @T.Popović But this is answering a _different_ question than that posed above. So, in that sense, it doesn't actually answer the question!