# Redirect index.php to root

Tags: .htaccess, url

I've done this before, it was like a line of code. Now when I look for it, it's all 5-10 lines for just redirecting index.php to root (`/`) in .htaccess.

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9369917/htaccess-redirect-index-php-to-root-including-subdomains

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code works for me

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index.php 
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

might it be something like this that you are looking for:

```
Redirect 301 /index.php http://www.yoursite.com/folder/
```