# why does hosted website shows index.php with domain name?

Tags: php, html

why does my website hosted on php server shows www.abc.com/index.php, and why not www.abc.com

all the webpages are lying in one folder only.

how to correct it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: That is because `index.php` is the default start up page.

Comment: ..Does it really matter

Comment: Maybe some htaccess might help.

Comment: @EdHeal yeah, i do not like it. can i use www.abc.com only?

Comment: What happens when you open www.abc.com? is it redirected to www.abc.com/index.php? or it lists directory?

Comment: @SaurabhSharma it is redirected to www.abc.com/index.php instead it shall show only www.abc.com

Comment: @user3227443 Check your Redirection settings on your server first. if there is any redirection, remove it.

Comment: What webhost are you using?

Comment: @EdHeal this is not the answer to question instead it is saying, you have disease, do not go to doctor, just forget u have disease. you will be alright.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [Apache documentation for DirectoryIndex](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex), simply put the following in a `.htaccess` file in the same directory as `index.php`:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index\.php 
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]

DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
```

Answer (score 0):

[@ThinkingMonkey Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9369917/htaccess-redirect-index-php-to-root-including-subdomains/9372938#9372938)

.htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index\.php 
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: in your .htaccess on the root

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your htaccess.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```