# Dynamic menu with REQUEST_URI works for '/' root but not '/index.php'

Tags: php, html, oop

What the following code does is that it checks for all the navigation items in a array, makes a html lists out of that and then check the `URI` matches to know which menu item should be displayed as active.

Everything works as it should. But there is one thing.

When I am on the root `domain.com` the `Home` item from the menu is shown as active as it should. But when I go to `/index.php` the same thing should happen but it doesn't I want them **both** to work.

I'm not too sure where or how I would implement that in my code.

**PHP**

```
<?php
$GLOBALS['config'] = array(
    'navigation' => array(
        'Home' => '/', //this part here
        'Sign up' => '/signup.php',
        'Login' => '/login.php'
    )
);

class Navigation {
    public static function get() {
        $URI = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        $navArr = Config::get('navigation');

        $navigation = '<ul id="nav">' . "\n";
        foreach($navArr as $name => $path) {
            $navigation .= '    <li' . (($URI == $path) ? ' class="active"' : false) . '><a href="' . $path . '">' . $name . '</a></li>' . "\n";
        }
        $navigation .= '</ul>';

        return $navigation;
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**PHP**

```
<?php
$GLOBALS['config'] = array(
    'navigation' => array(
        'Home'     => array('/', '/index.php'),
        'Sign up'  => array('/signup', '/signup.php'),
        'Log in'   => array('/login', '/login.php')
    )
);

class Navigation {
    public static function get() {
        $URI = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        $navArr = Config::get('navigation');

        $navigation = '<ul id="nav">' . "\n";
        foreach($navArr as $name => $path) {
            $navigation .= '    <li' . ((in_array($URI, $path)) ? ' class="active"' : false) . '><a href="' . $path[1] . '">' . $name . '</a></li>' . "\n";
        }
        $navigation .= '</ul>';

        return $navigation;
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

index.php is not in your navigation array, thats why.

add an entry like:
'index' => '/index.php'

that's a problem because u can't assign 2 pages to the same key the way u implemented it

or:
make a redirection on ur htacess so / and index.php are the same

something like this:
[htaccess redirect index.php to root (including subdomains)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9369917/htaccess-redirect-index-php-to-root-including-subdomains)

---

and a third option, make array with indexes and fields navitem and page:

> ```
> 'navigation' => array(
>     0 => array('nav' => 'Home',
>                 'page' => '/'),
> //and so on
> )
> ```

i'd definitely go htaccess

Comment: If I add an entry I basically get 2 items in my menu that point to the same page. I don't want that.

Comment: thats because of how u implemented. go .htaccess then