# How to redirect index.php to / using 301 redirect on apache2 Webserver

Tags: apache, redirect, ubuntu-14.04

I am trying to redirect the `index.php` to `/`, at the Document root: `/var/www/` by configuring the `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default` file.
*Using Ubuntu 14.04 Server with apache2*.

These are the contents of the Directory directive at /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default:

Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
     AllowOverride None
     Require all granted

This is what I've tried from [another question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9369917/htaccess-redirect-index-php-to-root-including-subdomains):

```
<Directory "/var/www">
     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
     AllowOverride None
     Require all granted
     RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^/index.php$
     RewriteRule $(.*)^ / [R=301,L]
</Directory>
```

I've even tried this `RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.(php|html?)$ /$1 [R=301,NC,L]`, and also `RedirectMatch 301 ^/index.php$ http://www.example.com` (this time I removed, the `RewriteCond`).

**What happens**
I can normally access my site from `/`, but when I add `/index.php` I get redirected to `wwww.mydomain.com` (notice the 4 **w**s).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I assume the extra "w" is coming from somewhere else. Is there anything else you can share?

Comment: @cleaver Yes that's what I think as well, could you please suggest some other files to look?