# I want to redirect index.html to main domain name in https

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect https://www.example.com/index.html to main domain name in https://www.example.com
I have SSL for my domain, so I need redirection https only.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [htaccess redirect index.php to root (including subdomains)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9369917/htaccess-redirect-index-php-to-root-including-subdomains)

Comment: This question is very unclear. You appear to be saying that you want to redirect a URL back to itself. Can you perhaps rephrase what you're trying to accomplish?

If what you're saying is "remove index.html" from the end of a requested URL, I *so* look forward to the day when people realize what an enormous waste of time this is, and go back to solving actual problems.