# How to automatically include Index.php in URL

Tags: php, linux

I'm trying to use "mantisbt" on VirtualMachine so when I access with "https://ip@" I get this error:

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access / on this server.
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

And when I use:

```
https://ip@/mantisbt-1.3.3/index.php
```

All works fine!

So how can I access my web page without the need to put all the URL?

Comment: May be you need to add `.htaccess` file to call index.php file to root. check this link for more info : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9369917/htaccess-redirect-index-php-to-root-including-subdomains

Comment: I found multiple file in my folder `./doc/.htaccess
./library/.htaccess
./core/.htaccess
./lang/.htaccess
./plugins/.htaccess
./config/.htaccess
./scripts/.htaccess ` which one should i use ?

Comment: You need to add new `.htaccess` on your root folder.

Comment: I still have the same problem i added .htaccess in /var/www/html also in /var/www/html/mantibt-1.3.3

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2384423/index-php-not-loading-by-default